# Sci-fi book about a body transfer called ‘body’ something by a female author possibly named Sue

Tags: story-identification, books

Trying to identify a book I saw today that I’ve forgotten. It’s a story where a woman has her head/brain transferred into another woman. I think the author's name is Sue something.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is [Second Body](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Title-Second-Body-Sue-Payer/dp/0505513811) by Sue Payer.

[This review](https://sfmistressworks.wordpress.com/2014/09/02/second-body-sue-payer/) (which I might add describes the novel as poorly written and offensively sexist on pretty much every level) gives an indication of the blurb;

> Wendy Anderson went into hospital to give birth to her second child.
> But the procedure goes badly wrong, and she dies on the operating
> table. At the same time, the body of Jennifer Bowman is brought into
> the same hospital. She had tumbled down a flight of stairs, suffered a
> head injury, and has now been pronounced brain-dead. So the doctors
> perform a procedure up to that point performed only on animal test
> subjects: they transplant Wendy’s head onto Jennifer’s body. The
> operation is kept secret from the press for twelve months in order to
> give the Anderson family time to adjust. The family also moves south
> to Florida and cuts all ties with their friends so that no one learns
> of the transplant. Because Wendy, once petite and “doll-like”, a
> “cuddle bunny”, now has a voluptuous body more than a foot taller.

[image: Cover of "Second Body". A gray cover with the upper half of two women's bodies visible, and the tagline "The shocking story of the ultimate transplant!"]

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you for finding it but I think I’ll avoid it if that’s the case! Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I do like that cover, though. The novel takes women and boils them down to *sexy bodies,* but the cover then takes the complexity of sexy bodies and boils it down to *bigger boobs*. Something about that feels exactly right for the book.